# Regex for capturing image src attribute

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to extract all image links within double quotations.

I'm able to get text within quotes by using

```
/"([^"]*)"/
```

but I want to get only those values which match following pattern

```
"https://text/text/.../text.jpg?text=text&text=..."
```

*(... Represents similar values)*

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What did you try so far? And is regex your only option?

Comment: I tried this `/"([^"]*)"/` but it gives all values. I want to filter results by given link pattern. I want to use regex alone

Comment: Try `"(https?:\/\/[^"\s]+\.jpg[^"\s]*)"` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zp2FMB/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the url has to start with http and optional s and it has to contain `.jpg` you might make your pattern a  bit more specific:

```
"(https?:\/\/[^"\s]+\/\S+?\.jpg[^"\s]*)"
```

- `"(` Match opening " and start capturing group

  - `https?:\/\/` Match http with optional s and ://
  - `[^"\s]+` Match not " or a whitespace char
  - `\/\S+?\.jpg` Match a forward slash, 1+ times a non whitespace char non greedy and .jpg
  - `[^"\s]*` Match 0+ times not a whitespace char or " to match what follows the file extension
- `)"` Close capturing group and match closing "

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hIs5JN/1)

```js
let pattern = /"(https?:\/\/[^"\s]+\/\S+?\.jpg[^"\s]*)"/;
[
  '"https://text/text/.../text.jpg?text=text&text=..."',
  '"https://text/text/.../text.jpg?t&ext=text&text=..."',
  '"https://text/text/.../text.jpg?text=text"'
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(pattern)[1]))
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/['"]+/g
```

should work

```
let urlStr= "https://text/text/........./text.jpg?text=text&text=.......';
console.log(urlStr.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trial is pretty good. Here, we can also use a simple left and right `"` boundary and collect the data in between:

```
"(.+?)"
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hzm8fy/1)

```js
const regex = /"(.+?)"/gm;
const str = `"https://text/text/........./text<b>.jpg?text=text&text=.......</b>"`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```